# Numerical differentiation: 2-point vs 5-point method

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

I want to compare the following two numerical differentiation schemes:

2-point numerical differentiation:
\begin{equation}
\dot{\omega}_t = \frac{1}{dt} \left [ \omega_{t} - \omega_{t-dt} \right ] + \mathcal{O}(h)
\end{equation}

5-point numerical differentiation:
\begin{equation}
\dot{\omega}_t = -\frac{1}{12dt} \left [ -25\omega_{t} + 48\omega_{t-dt} -36\omega_{t-2dt} + 16\omega_{t-3dt} - 3\omega_{t-4dt} \right ] + \mathcal{O}(h^4)
\end{equation}

The data that I use can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xqbxi22ezu932p/tempdat.mat?dl=0), where $p$ is the signal without noise, $pnoisy$ is signal $p$ plus independent Gaussian noise, $pdot$ is the exact derivative of $p$ which needs to be estimated by using $pnoisy$. At last, $time$ is simply the time vector.

I use the following Matlab script:

```
clear all; clc; close all

load tempdat

%   Two-point method
time_step = time(2) - time(1);

pdot_twopoint = (1/time_step)*diff(pnoisy);

%   Five-point method
j = 1;
for i = 5:length(time)
    pdot_fivepoint(j,1) = -(1/(12*time_step))*(-25*pnoisy(i) + 48*pnoisy(i-1) - 36*pnoisy(i-2) + 16*pnoisy(i-3) - 3*pnoisy(i-4));
    j = j+1;
end

plot(time, pdot)
hold all
plot(time(2:end), pdot_twopoint)
plot(time(5:end), pdot_fivepoint)
hold off
legend('real','2-point','5-point')
xlabel('time (s)')
ylabel('pdot')

sum(abs(pdot(2:end) - pdot_twopoint).^2)
sum(abs(pdot(5:end) - pdot_fivepoint).^2)
```

The RMSE (w.r.t. to $pdot$ and its estimate) of the 2-point method is 3.2038, while the RMSE of the 5-point method is 47.4570. I have also added a graph below where it can be seen that the 2-point method results in a more accurate estimate of $pdot$ compared to the 5-point method.

I wonder why the 5-point method performs better than the 2-point method, because the accuracy of the 5-point method is supposed to be $\mathcal{O}(h^4)$ while that of the 2-point method is $\mathcal{O}(h)$.

[image]

Comment: The error estimates for the 2, 5 point methods depend on the 3rd, 5th derivatives of $f$ which is noisy (hence the derivatives are likely to be large). Is this for a real time application? Can you filter the noise first?

Comment: High order is not high accuracy.  High order ($h^4$ for the five point method) means the method is very accurate for nice smooth functions with well behaved fifth derivatives.  Taking derivatives enhances noise, which is the source of your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to estimate a function from NOISY estimates of the function values, you should use something like local polynomial regression, implemented for example in the function loess() in the programming language R. MATLAB might also have something similar in the statistics tool box but I'm not sure.

Another approach, if you suspect your true underlying function is smooth and you have an idea for the magnitude of noise as well as how much the true function varies vertically (amplitude) and how quickly the function varies horizontally (bandwidth), you can fit a Gaussian process to your noisy data. I'm not sure if/where this is implemented as standard in R or MATLAB though.

The problem with using noisy estimates from the function directly in a standard fitting method that assumes no noise is that as you get a finer and finer grid of function estimates, all of the apparent derivatives will diverge and in fact the function won't even appear continuous.